# Form validation with variable input list in Angular?

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-material

Alright, so here's the problem. I have a list of questions that are either inputs, or mat selection lists. This is a child component to a parent that can spawn up multiple versions of this form with differing questions. 
What I need to figure out is how to be able to validate every input or selection list is answered in some way before setting some variable to the parent that the form is complete.

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
  <mat-step *ngFor="let question of formQuestionsFormatted">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>{{ question.questionText}}</ng-template>
      <mat-label>{{ question.questionText }}</mat-label>

      <mat-form-field class="inputForm" *ngIf="!question.isSurveyOptionList">
        <input matInput placeholder="Answer" [(ngModel)]="question.responseInputText">
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-radio-group *ngIf="question.isSurveyOptionList" [(ngModel)]="question.responseOptionSelected">
        <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let option of question.surveyOptionList" [value]="option">
          {{option.optionText}}
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are several solutions to your question, but one way of achieving this would be by using Reactive Forms.

You would loop through your "formQuestionsFormatted" in the ngOnInit of your component and create what is called a "FormArray" in Reactive Forms. In your FormArray you would have one FormControl for each question, and you would set 'Validators.required' on all of them.

Then when you want to check if it is valid you can call 'myFormArray.valid', and it will be true only if all your questions have been answered.

(You would need to read up on Reactive Forms if you have not used them before. They are very powerful when you want to do complex forms, but it can take some time to learn how to use them.)